# Clustering with constraint size

Tags: clustering

I want a clustering method which can let me apply constraints on the maximum and the minimum cluster sizes which I can implement. Otherwise suggestions for a combination of existing techniques which I could use to get the same result are welcome.

Comment: Could you please share why you are planning to put constraints on the cluster sizes? As most people are interested in seeing the nodes of the dendrogram to decide the clustering level, so your intention sounds to be interesting to me.

Comment: How do you define word "size"? Number of objects in a cluster? "Diameter" (distance between utmost points) in a cluster? Mean squared or absolute deviation in a cluster? Else?

Comment: Size is the number of objects in the cluster, @BlainWaan it is not that fascinating, the constraint size on the group has always been there, just that now I was planning on getting the groups from clustering.
One thing that I am tempted to try is to cluster them using any method and then go on to break them if their size is more than permitted.